# How to translate Excel Solver problem with conditional function constraint into R?

Tags: r, excel, solver

I am trying to translate an Excel Solver problem (which solves correctly) into R code. I am aware that there is an array of packages allowing to solve constrained optimisation problems, but I still have not found one being able to formulate my problem and solve it.

The problem is the following

```
min sum(x)

s.t.:
g(f(x)) > 0.9

where:
x is a vector of boolean parameters to be identified
f(x) = x+4
g(f(x)) = SUMIF(f(x), "<90", M)/1000

M is a vector of constant terms with length equal to the lenght of the parameters of X.
```

In words, the problem aims at minimising the objective function sum(x). Here, x is the vector of boolean parameters the value of which must be determined, f(x) is a function which sums 4 to each parameter, and g(f(x)) is the conditional (to the value of each corresponding f(x)) sum of the vector of constant terms M.

I struggle to set up the problem with every constrained optimisation R package I have found. Is this problem solvable in R in the first place? If so, how?

Comment: `x+4` is less than `90` for every component since `x` is a 0/1 vector so the `sumif` equals `sum(M)` independently of `x`.  I suspect that there is an error in the problem statement.

Comment: Could be, the problem I posted is really a demo example. My issue is how to translate a problem of this kind - which is handled by Excel solver - into R.